# parse_date_time returns a vector of NA

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to convert a large column into a datetime value from a factor.

I get the following error

```
parse_date_time(Data,"Ymd H")  
#[1] NA
```

> Warning message:
>   All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

The strings in the table are structured as

```
Oct 22 18:50:08  2012
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in base R, but the trouble is reading `?strptime` to know which format to use.

```
as.POSIXct("Oct 22 18:50:08 2012", format = "%b %d %T %Y", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2012-10-22 18:50:08 UTC"
```

If you want to use `parse_date_time` you can use

```
lubridate::parse_date_time("Oct 22 18:50:08 2012","mdTY")
#[1] "2012-10-22 18:50:08 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anytime` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anytime("Oct 22 18:50:08 2012")
#[1] "2012-10-22 18:50:08 EDT"
```